# How to update record in SQL Server but only with non null values from parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table with columns `ID` and `A` to `G` (`ID, A, B, C, D, E, F, G`).

I need to create a stored procedure that takes ID of record and 7 parameters that can be NULL.

That stored procedure should update the columns in the record identified by the ID passed in, but only the columns that have corresponding parameters that are NOT NULL.

There is a bit more logic in that stored procedure. Now it is done by doing 7 NULL checks and up to 7 updates for single record. Is there any way to do it in one UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
update t
    a = coalesce(@a, a),
    b = coalesce(@b, b),
    . . .
where id = @id;
```